# Node.js vm: how to terminate Script by external event (not using timeout)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any way to create mechanism giving you ability to terminate running script in Node.js VM (Script.runInContext(...))?
More about task:
I shouldn't use timer, we already use this variant, but we need additional one, to do it manually.
I need to track all running scripts inside the VM, to have a table showing all  running scripts, with button, by pushing which I can stop selected script.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

You simply need to put a click event on the button that you want to use to terminate the process, and pass in the global `process` object and call it's `exit()`method for the callback.

Try the following

`btn.on('click', process.exit())`